# удалить символы из определенного интервала строки и вставки на их место другую строку С++

Tags: c++, строки

помогите с задачей, очень прошу!
готов и очень хочу разбираться

Разработать функцию, которая возвращает строку символов, которая получена из строки S1 путём удаления символов с позиции N1 до позиции N2 и вставки на это место строки S2. Строка может быть любого типа

заранее спасибо

Comment: Как строка может быть любого типа ? Это или строка или (не строка) другой тип.

Comment: @noname2019, имеется в виду, что тип может быть как char, так и string